# How to export chrome user certificate

Tags: certificate, chrome

In ubuntu, I recently installed a client certificate in google chrome, and now I want to export it to other browsers. I installed the libnss3-tools package, but can't find the export option for certutil.

Comment: It would help others if you tagged this with the Operating System you are referring to here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is

```
pk12util -o certfile.p12 -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -n <certificate's name>
```

The certificate's name is obtained running

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this to get my startssl.com cert out of Google Chrome in Linux. I could then import the cert into Firefox and all is well.

```
$ pk12util -o certfile.p12 -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -n "StartCom Free Certificate Member's StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Client CA ID"
```